# post body empty when using httpclient on android

Tags: android, post, httpclient, urlconnection

**Context**: In Android, when I use Java's HttpURLConnection object as shown below, I see the POST body correctly on the server side. However, when I use what I believe is the equivalent HttpClient code, the POST body is empty.

**Question**:

1. What am I missing?
2. Server-side is a Django-python server. I have set up a debug point at the entry point of this endpoint but the post body is already empty. How can I debug through it to find out why the body is null?

*Note*: I already looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8325212/requesting-post-full-body-but-receiving-get-empty-body-on-servers-side-via-h) , but the solution does not work for me.

Code: using HttpURLConnection - this works:

```
try {
    URL url = new URL("http://10.0.2.2:8000/accounts/signup/"); 
    String charset = "UTF-8";
    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
    connection.setDoOutput(true);
    connection.setRequestProperty  ("Authorization", "Basic base64encodedstring==");
    connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", charset);
    connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", 
        "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=" + charset);
    connection.setDoInput(true);

    StringBuilder sb =  new StringBuilder();
    sb.append("appver=6&user=value1pw=&hash=h1");

    OutputStreamWriter outputWriter = new 
        OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
    outputWriter.write(sb.toString());
    outputWriter.flush();
    outputWriter.close();
    // handle response
} catch () { 
    // handle this 
}
```

============================================================

Code: using Apache httpclient - does NOT work - server gets empty POST body:

```
    HttpPost mHttpPost = new HttpPost(""http://10.0.2.2:8000/accounts/signup/"");
    mHttpPost.addHeader("Authorization", "Basic base64encodedstring==");
    mHttpPost.addHeader("Content-Type", 
        "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8");
    mHttpPost.addHeader("Accept-Charset", "UTF-8");

    String str = "appver=6&user=value1pw=&hash=h1"; // same as the above
    StringEntity strEntity = new StringEntity(str);
    mHttpPost.setEntity(strEntity);

    HttpUriRequest pHttpUriRequest = mHttpPost; 

    DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    httpResponse = client.execute(pHttpUriRequest);
    // more code
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured the reason why this was happening:

The authorization header in the POST request had an extra new line character "\n" - this was causing the request to go through to the server side handler, but with the body getting cut off. I have never noticed this behavior before.

Comment: @Yati, Yes, as indicated above, the reason this error came up was because of extraneous characters at the endof the auth header. Check yours by trimming the header to eliminate these spaces